# PayPal IPN Simulator Not Sending Request

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am having troubles with the PayPal IPN simulator, which does not even appear to be connecting to my site.  Although I am supplying a URL that works from the public Internet, through the IPN Simulator I am receiving the error:

IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information.

Although some other posts have indicated that old SSL libraries could cause problems, I have tried:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 \
-showcerts -cert /etc/httpd/ssl/{my-server-cert} \
-key /etc/httpd/ssl/{my-server-key}
```

from my server and receive:

Verify return code: 0 (ok)

which I *think* indicates that the SSL handshake is NOT the problem.  Is that correct?

Is anyone else experiencing this problem, and can anyone verify wether the PayPal IPN Simulator is actually -- ever! -- sending out any requests, or is it just completely broken?  I have gotten no useful response from contacting PayPal support (via e-mail, via web ticket, via calling customer support).

I am seeing nothing in my logs to indicate that PayPal is even attempting to connect.  I have seen posts saying that the IPN Simulator is sometimes unreliable, but I have not seen a single request go through, although I have only been testing since yesterday (but have probably tried it a few dozen times, trying to tweak different things and at different times, hoping to see anything at all come through.)

Answer (score 0):

The IPN simulator is work fine (I was using it a few days ago), but your conditions need to be perfect I found. If there are errors in your backend code (I was using php), then it won't return the handshake. The best guide I could find for the rest of it was here: https://gist.github.com/xcommerce-gists/3440401#file-completelistener-php 
 The cacerts file needs to be there for the actual live IPN to work, but the listener will work without it. Also make sure you have your curl libraries installed on apache if you're using linux.